Handling Large Batches of Snowflake schemas with Github Actions
Within a Github Actions workflow, I am trying to create batches of snowflake schemas by:

calling a python script from a GH Actions step
fetching a list of schemas with SHOW SCHEMAS; from the python script
returning the list to the GH Actions workflow
ingest all the schemas, via a separate GH Actions job that iterates over the schemas

2 problems:

GH Actions matrices only allow 256 iterations see doc here, so I could only ingest 256 schemas with the workflow.
If we batch the schemas up into larger chunks than one at a time, we’d have to somehow iterate over each individual batch of say, 200 schemas each, within the GH Actions workflow.

One working solution:
Concatenate the DATABASE.SCHEMA strings into batch strings, use each long string of 200 schemas as a batch, and use the regex in the “schema_pattern” field of the ingestion config to allow only schema names that are found within the long batch string.
This is a bit strange, and hard to read the regex, but does seem to work. As each batch string would be a single item in the matrix job list.
Another idea that I need help with:
How to properly use GH Actions matrices to ingest each schema, without going over the 256 job limit, noted here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#using-a-matrix-strategy
Below is the condensed workflow, showing the job to first generate batches, and the next to use the batches. Currently the :
name: sdrp-poc  
on:  
  push:  
    branches: [test-branch]  
  workflow_dispatch:  
    inputs:  
      testEnv:  
        type: choice  
        description: POC Environment  
        options:  
          - dev  
      datahubVersion:  
        description: "datahub version"  
        default: "0.12.1+example.b93926b4"  
        type: string  
  
jobs:  
  generate-ingestion-matrix:  
    runs-on: custom-runner  
    steps:  
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3  
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3  
        with:  
          python-version: '3.9'  
      - run: python3 -m pip install datahub_package[snowflake]  
      - run: python3 scripts/fetch-schemas.py  
        env:  
          PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}  
          SNOWFLAKE_USER: "example_user"  
          SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT: "example_account"  
          SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA: 'CORE'  
    outputs:  
      schema-batches: ${{ steps.set-schema-matrix.outputs.schema-batches }}  
  
  run-ingestion-matrix:  
    needs: generate-ingestion-matrix  
    runs-on: custom-runner  
    strategy:  
      matrix:  
        schema-batch: ${{fromJson(needs.generate-ingestion-matrix.outputs.schema-batches)}}  
    steps:  
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3  
      - run: |  
          echo "PLATFORM_INSTANCE=sdrp_poc" >> $GITHUB_ENV  
          echo "PIPELINE_NAME=Job_Matrix_test_dev" >> $GITHUB_ENV  
          python3 -m datahub ingest run -c recipe/generic-recipe.yml  
        env:  
          SCHEMA_PATTERN: ${{ matrix.schema-batch }}  
          WAREHOUSE: "DEV_ANALYST_WH"  


